# Change of Ownership Causes Nautilus to crash how can I change it back?

Tags: nautilus, chown, solr

Installing Solr I change the ownership of a folder called solr ... usr/share/solr-4.5.1/example/solr/ to `tomcat7` but now when I try to change it back nautilus keeps switching off I have changed the owner back to ed, but it still is doing it in nautilus.

The original owner was Me to start with: What have I done, Why does nautilus keep crashing when I look at the permissions on this folder and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the crash is probably a bug. [You should report it.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) If you want to change ownership you can use:

```
sudo chown -R someuser:somegroup /usr/share/solr-4.5.1/example/solr/
```

Be careful that you don't mess up something else.

> What have I done

You can't change ownership of files that are not longer yours, that's most likely the cause why Nautilus crash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- So am i not nescessarily the owner of the file even if i am the only user on this computer?

Comment: Exactly, Ubuntu has many users for different stuff. You can check all the users in your system `awk -F':' '{print $1}' /etc/passwd`